# AngularJS ng-repeat - Cannot Get Module or Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Fairly new to AngularJS so I might have tried to run through this far too quickly.

I'm trying to display an img, a date and a string repeat into a div with AngularJS but no matter what I do I keep getting the same {{ x.name }} displaying instead of the data inside the array.

Here's the header:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myApp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here's the section that I'm trying to automate:

```
<section id="angular-section" ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>ANGULAR SECTION</h1>
    <div class="main" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-repeat="x in employees">
                <div class="headshot"> <img src="{{ x.cover }}">
                    <p>{{ x.name }}</p>
                    <p>{{ x.strtdate | date }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's the contents of controller.js :

```
angular
.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.employees = [
                {
                    name: 'Jamie Bohanna',
                    strtdate: new Date('2014', '03', '08'), 
                    cover: 'img/JH.jpg',
                }
                , /* etc..... */
];
        });
```

Here's the myApp.js :

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

When trying to access either controller.js or myApp.js I get this error:

```
Cannot GET /controller.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**: Snippet added

Remove `[]` on *controller.js* since you're already creating the app on *myApp.js* when you put `angular.module("myApp", [])` (notice the `[]` here).

On *controller.js* you just have to put the following in order to locate the module (since it was already created):

```
angular
.module('myApp') //removed the [] since the app was already created on myApp.js
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.employees = [
// rest of your controller...
```

Also, there was a missing `]` at  the end of the code

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        
        $scope.employees = [{
          name: 'Jamie Bohanna',
          strtdate: new Date('2014', '03', '08'),
          cover: 'img/JH.jpg',
        }];
        
      }]);//this ] was missing
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section id="angular-section" ng-app="myApp">
  <h1>ANGULAR SECTION</h1>
  <div class="main" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <div ng-repeat="x in employees">
        <div class="headshot">
          <img src="{{ x.cover }}">
          <p>{{ x.name }}</p>
          <p>{{ x.strtdate | date }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, But i'm still not getting the data displayed in the view?

Comment: Any errror on console devtool?

Comment: Oh, that's probably because the cdn resource cannot be found (maybe some connectivity issues). Could you try using a local version of AngulaJS file? Also make sure your files (`controller.js` and `myApp.js` are linked properly, so you don't get a 404 with them, you, know, that means they aren't found and this means no data will be shown

Comment: @WebDev-InTraining, take a look at the snippet I just made, It contains your very same code. I just fixed the commented issues before and added a missin `]` at the end of your code. This should work for you too